# Association on Remote Databases in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm trying to set up an association between two views in a database I have no control over. It's a relationship between people and their jobs, each person has many jobs and each job belongs to one person. Here's the person table:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'PER_VW'
  self.primary_key = 'EMPLID'

  has_many :jobs, foreign_key: 'EMPLID'
end
```

And the job table:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'JOB_VW'

  belongs_to :person, foreign_key: 'EMPLID'
end
```

From the console I can run `Person.where(emplid: '0037485').jobs` and I don't get an error, but I don't get any results either. If I instead do:

```
p = Person.where(emplid: '0037485').first()
Job.where(emplid: p.emplid)
```

I get the results I expect. It is an oracle database, I'm using the following gems to connect:

```
gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.1.7'
gem "activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter", "~> 1.5.0"
```

EDIT: As per Lurker's recommendation, I added the `foreign_key: 'EMPLID'` to both tables and I still get no results. Here is this SQL that I see in the console:

```
irb(main):004:0> p.jobs
Job Load (36.5ms)  SELECT "JOB_VW".* FROM "JOB_VW"  
WHERE "JOB_VW"."EMPLID" = :a1  [[nil, nil]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I imagine that `[nil, nil]` array has something to do with it. But I'm not sure why it would be empty.

Comment: In addition to my prior suggestion, I think `Person.where(emplid: '0037485').jobs` is incorrect because `where` returns a collection which, in this case, is a collection consisting of one item. Try getting the "first" item from the collection, per my updated answer.

Comment: I would expect `Person.where(emplid: '0037485').jobs` to throw an error without the `.first` being in there. It's puzzling why `p.jobs` is coming back empty when `p = Person.where(emplid: '0037485').first`. If it is, then my updated suggestion may not solve this completely.

Comment: This is a pretty straight-forward association and should work. I use this and some other more complex relations in a remote MS SQL database from Rails and it works fine. Perhaps there's a problem with the Oracle adapter. Do you have a choice of any alternative adapters to try?

Comment: Thank you for offering some suggestions. I must have had `.first` in the chain and just not copied it into my question properly, because it didn't throw an error. I updated the question to include that. I'll see if I can find an alternative adapter. Could the problem also be related to the fact that my `Job` model doesn't have a primary key? There isn't one clearly defined in the view, though I could figure out a composite key.

Comment: That's a good question. I don't see why the lack of a primary key in the `Job` model should interfere with the creation of a valid query for obtaining the jobs associated with a given employee Id. But, maybe internal to the methods it matters.

Comment: I tested associations on some other tables and it gave me the same problems. I can't imagine the oracle adapter would be very well received if it actually couldn't handle associations very well, so I'm going to assume it's a problem with the way these views I have access to are set up. I tried a few different versions of the same gem, `"activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter"`, but I couldn't find any other adapter that was recently updated. I'll post a new question about working around this issue. Thanks your insights. It helps to at least get feedback from someone that it *should* work.

Comment: I agree with you that a problem with the adapter would be very unlikely. Your setup is very straightforward, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. I use an external database for MS SQL even with custom class names and more complex relations, and it all works. Just in case it does have something to do with the lack of primary key in `Job`, you could try including a primary key method similar to what's shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018767/a-has-many-bs-where-b-has-no-primary-key, just to see if that makes it behave.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a foreign key in the association, you need to specify it in the other model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'JOB_VW'

  belongs_to :person, foreign_key: 'EMPLID'
end
```

Otherwise, it will assume `person_id`.

In simple cases, depending upon what your app does with the models, you may be able to omit the `foreign_key` from the `has_many` in the `Person` model. I usually include it in both models regardless.

EDIT: When you do the query, the association operates on an instance, not on a collection. So, rather than `Person.where(emplid: '0037485').jobs` which attempts to get `jobs` for an ActiveRecord Relation consisting of one person, try it this way, which gets the first person in the collection, then gets the jobs:

```
Person.where(emplid: '0037485').first.jobs
```

Alternatively, this may work since the employee ID is the primary key:

```
Person.find('0037485').jobs
```